# Find a symmetric matrix that has the same eigenvalues, without computing them

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a square real matrix. Is there a way to construct a symmetric matrix that has the same eigenvalues as my matrix? I don't want to compute the eigenvalues of my matrix.

Comment: A necessary condition is that your initial matrix has all its eigenvalues real...

Comment: Your post lacks sufficient detail to determine whether what you want is possible.  It would of course only be possible if your "square real matrix" is diagonalizable.

Comment: @hardmath This is all the information that I have. I want to know if it is possible with this much generality or not.

Comment: @AnneBauval You are correct. I only want to preserve the eigenvalues.

Comment: If you are saying you don't actually have the matrix, only that it is square and real, then you don't have enough information to decide if a symmetric real matrix shares the same eigenvalues.   Does that help?

Comment: The answer is "no". It is not possible in all generality, because (as I said), a symmetric matrix must have real eigenvalues. For example it is not possible for any antisymmetric matrix like this one : $$\begin{pmatrix}\ \ 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: As Jean Marie said, your matrix must necessarily have real eigen values. Assuming you want the symmetric matrix of the same dimension as your original matrix, original must have enough eigen vectors. A counterexample would be a rotation of of 2d real plane which doesn't necessarily have any eigenvectors. Since symmetric matrix always has at least 1 eigenvalue if dimension is not 0, such a symmetric matrix for a rotation does not exist in general.